# php: simple template engine

Tags: php, templates

I have a function called `load_template()`

this function has two parameters

- $name => the name of the template
- $vars => array of key => value variables to be replaced in the template.

the way I want this to work is.

in the template ('test') I want to be able to write

```
<?php echo $title; ?>
```

then call

```
load_template('test', array('title' => 'My Title'));
```

and have it fill it out.

how can I do this?

---

**Output buffering method.**
I have come up with the code below.
I am sure it can be improved.

```
public static function template($name, $vars = array()) {
  if (is_file(TEMPLATE_DIR . $name . '.php')) {
    ob_start();
    extract($vars);
    require(TEMPLATE_DIR . $name . '.php');
    $contents = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $contents;
  }
  throw new exception('Could not load template file \'' . $name . '\'');
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have so far?

Comment: ob-way is okay if you need to return the contents. However, I see no use for this, save for some rare exceptional cases. Why not to let it go straight to the browser?

Comment: Whats wrong with standard includes? Are you templating the variable names? why is $title = "My Title"; include "test.templ" insufficient?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
function load_template($name, $vars)
{
  extract($vars);
  include $name;
}
```

Wrap with [ob_start](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and [ob_get_clean](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php) if you want to capture the output in a variable.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
function load_template($name, $vars)
{
  include('template/'.$name.'.tpl'); //.tpl, .inc, .php, whatever floats your boat
}
```

and in `template/whatever.tpl` you'd have:

```
...
<title><?php echo $vars['title'] ?></title>
...

...
<?php if (!empty($vars['content'])): //template still needs to know if the content is empty to display the div ?>
    <div id="content">
<?php echo $vars['content']; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
...
```

Of course, that assumes the output being printed directly.
You could have the tpl file print directly, or produce a string, or buffer the output from the tpl file and return it from `load_template`

Comment: not quite. I want to be able to return the loaded template as a string once it it processed.

also, I would add in extract($vars) so that the variables do not have to be referenced from an array.

Comment: yea, `extract` was the way to go in this case. I'd completely forgotten about it actually, just make sure you handle the cases of `$vars['vars']` and `$vars['name']` properly.

Comment: Get rid of all that if (!empty crap. it's business logic job. A template should be always supplied with full set of variables